# Is there any way I can do to bind vue with something else apart from id?

Tags: vuejs2, bootstrap-modal

I am using vue2+bootstrap building a website. As problems appear, the quickest way to fix em is to bind vue with something else,like class rather than id. So, is there any (pls....pls.... tell me yes....) way I can use vue with it's bound to anything else? thx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I tell you yes.

The `el` option can be a CSS selector string or an actual HTMLElement.

More info in [official docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/index.html#el).

But I think id is a proper way when operating DOM in most cases, which avoids excessive responsibility for the class name.